# Taskbar won't hide when there are notifications

Tags: windows, taskbar, windows-11, notifications

My Windows 11 taskbar is set to hide automatically, however if there is a notification it will *not* hide until I have opened the program the notification came from (typically, an MS Teams message, or a new unread mail in Outlook):

[image]

This is a real 'pita' when I work remotely, because the fat taskbar overlaps anything that's full screen, and in the case of e.g. a VMWare session running Windows 10 the quick tray icons in there are almost impossible to access. The bottom part of the screen changes from:

[image]

into:

[image]

I have to go the program with the notification to stop this, interupting my workflow.

These are my current task bar settings (in Dutch):

[image]

I disabled the second setting for the badges, but the taskbar behavior stays the same, it just does not have the number:

[image]

**(How) can I force 'hide the taskbar' regardless of notifications?**

Keeping the taskbar visible is not an option, because it takes away too much screen real estate.

Comment: Try setting your VMware to a window that is almost but not quite full screen. Then ensure that the VMware window does not cover the Windows 11 task bar. I have VMware here and what I describe works.